# Resolving clang Warnings in a Simple C Scanner

Tags: c, file, io, clang

I have a basic C code with the intent of reading the contents of a file via opening a file, reading the contents and closing a file. Although the following code compiles and works, the clang compiler gives some extra warnings, which I was unable to address.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* scanFile(FILE *fl, char* ch);

int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    FILE *file;
    char *ch = "\0";

    ch = scanFile(file, ch);
    fclose(file);

    printf("%s\n", ch);
    return 0;
}

char* scanFile(FILE *fl, char* ch)
{
    fl = fopen("/tmp/test.txt", "r");
    if (fl)
    {
        while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) { putchar(ch); }
    }

    return ch;
}
```

When I try to compile my code, the following warnings are flashed by my clang.

```
clang scanFile scanFile.c 
scanFile.c:22:20: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'char *'    
from 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) { putchar(ch); }
               ^ ~~~~~~~~~
scanFile.c:22:33: warning: comparison between pointer and integer ('char *' and 'int')
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) { putchar(ch); }
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~
scanFile.c:22:51: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion passing 'char *' to parameter of type 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) { putchar(ch); }
                                              ^~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:172:17: note: passing argument to parameter here
int      putchar(int);
                ^
3 warnings generated.
ld: can't link with a main executable file 'scanFile' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

However, since the compilation process is devoid of any serious ERRORs, when I run the executable file generated as the result of my compilation above, I get the following on my screen (the following faux-latin is the file that should be read and outputted as so in my C code.)

```
Ergo ego senator inimicus, si ita vultis, homini, amicus esse, sicut semper fui, rei publicae debeo. 
Quid? si ipsas inimicitias, depono rei publicae causa, quis me tandem iure reprehendet, praesertim cum ego omnium meorum consiliorum atque factorum exempla semper ex summorum hominum consiliis atque factis mihi censuerim petenda.

Eodem tempore etiam Hymetii praeclarae indolis viri negotium est actitatum, cuius hunc novimus esse textum. 
Cum Africam pro consule regeret Carthaginiensibus victus inopia iam lassatis, ex horreis    
Romano populo destinatis frumentum dedit, pauloque postea cum provenisset segetum copia, integre sine ulla restituit mora.

Et hanc quidem praeter oppida multa duae civitates exornant Seleucia opus Seleuci regis, et Claudiopolis quam deduxit coloniam Claudius Caesar.
Isaura enim antehac nimium potens, olim subversa ut rebellatrix interneciva aegre vestigia claritudinis pristinae monstrat admodum pauca.
[1]    59823 segmentation fault  ./scanFile
```

NOTE: BUT IT ALSO GIVES A ' 59823 segmentation fault  ./scanfile ' error still.

EXTRA: clang -Wall gives;

```
C clang -Wall scanFile.c 
scanFile.c:10:19: warning: variable 'file' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]
    ch = scanFile(file, ch);
              ^~~~
scanFile.c:7:15: note: initialize the variable 'file' to silence this warning
    FILE *file;
          ^
               = NULL
scanFile.c:22:20: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'char *' from 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) { putchar(ch); }
               ^ ~~~~~~~~~
scanFile.c:22:33: warning: comparison between pointer and integer ('char *' and 'int')
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) { putchar(ch); }
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~
scanFile.c:22:51: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion passing 'char *' to parameter of type 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) { putchar(ch); }
                                              ^~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h:172:17: note: passing argument to parameter here
int      putchar(int);
                ^
4 warnings generated.
```

Comment: `char* ch` is pointer to `char` but `putchar/getchar` needs `int` type.

Comment: Compile with `-Werror`. Always compile with `-Werror` and now your "warnings" are errors. And then fix your errors.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "my code works"

Comment: @AnttiHaapala when I run the executable binary code which is the resultant (though the compiler gives WARNINGs - errors are different from WARNINGs) of the compilation procedure (in this case with warnings), the program works, though obviously I should resolve the warnings.

Comment: By 'works',  I mean I get the expected output. By all these means though, I know from my C knowledge that due to the warnings, there is no real guarantee the code should work.

Answer (score -2):

Ahmet you have a few errors in your code:

- You are not allocating memory for resulting string. When you define a string like you do `char *ch = "\0";` it is called `string literal`. Trying to modify a string literal is undefined behaviour. You can read more about string literals at [here](https://www.cs.uic.edu/~jbell/CourseNotes/C_Programming/CharacterStrings.html). This is giving you segmentation fault.
- You are trying to pass a file pointer to `scanFile` function, to close the file when the function is finished. But when you pass file pointer to `scanFile` function, it is passed by value. And compiler warning you that you didn't initialize it before passing it. When `scanFile` function opens the file and assigns the resulting file pointer to its parameter, it can not be accessable outside of the function. You have to return a file pointer to do that.
- You are using `getchar` to read a character from a file. It is used to get character from `stdin`. By default it get characters from keyboard. You should use `fgetc` to get character from a file.

Here is a working example for you which **UPDATED** for checking `errno` for possible `malloc` or `fopen` failure:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_BUFFER_SIZE 1000

struct {
    FILE *fPtr;
    char *text;
} typedef Result;

Result scanFile(const char *fileName);

int main(int argc, char const* argv[]) {
    Result result = scanFile("text.txt");
    printf("Result:\n%s\n", result.text);
    return 0;
    if (errno != 0) {
        printf("Program ended with error: %d\n", errno);
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Result:\n%s\n", result.text);
    // Close the file
    fclose(result.fPtr);
    // Free buffer
    free(result.text);
    return 0;
}

Result scanFile(const char *fileName) {

    Result result;

    result.text = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);

    if (result.text == NULL) {
        printf("scanFile: Faield to allocate memory!\n");
        printf("scanFile: %s\n", strerror( errno ));
        return result;
    }

    result.fPtr = fopen(fileName, "r");

    if (result.fPtr == NULL) {
        printf("scanFile: Faield to open file!\n");
        printf("scanFile: %s\n", strerror( errno ));
        return result;
    }

    unsigned int count = 0;
    int ch;

    while ((ch = fgetc(result.fPtr)) != EOF) {
        if (count < MAX_BUFFER_SIZE) {
            result.text[count] = ch;
            ++count;
        } else {
            printf("scanFile: Exceeded buffer size!\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: This is in no way exemplary code, what is the magic 1000, returning a structure, but no way of returning a failure, how about a malloc failure then, etc...

Comment: This answer points the errors OP is facing and gives him a better example code that doesn't have those errors.

Comment: The first problem here is the authors post which lacks a proper description of what they intend the code to do, judging by the fact that there are two completely different answers, and the authors of these posts have read the question differently. The author has not stepped forward and provided further information on what they intend the code to do. All they want to do is "silence warnings in working code", and it has been shown that the code does not work but OP still insists it is working.